# Need to make SQL subquery more efficient

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that contains all the pupils.

I need to look through my registered table and find all students and see what their current status is.

If it's `reg = y` then include this in the search, however student may change from `y` to `n` so I need it to be the most recent using `start_date` to determine the most recent reg status.

The next step is that if `n`, then don't pass it through. However if latest reg is = `y` then search the `pupil` table, using `pupilnumber`; if that pupil number is in the `pupils` table then add to count.

```
Select Count(*) 
From Pupils Partition(Pupils_01) 
Where Pupilnumber in (Select t1.pupilnumber 
                      From registered t1
                      Where T1.Start_Date = (Select Max(T2.Start_Date)
                                             From registered T2
                                             Where T2.Pupilnumber = T1.Pupilnumber)
                        And T1.reg = 'N');
```

This query works, but it is very slow as there are several records in the pupils table.

Just wondering if there is any way of making it more efficient

Comment: Do you have any indexes on your tables?  If you don't have an index on, at the very least, registered.start_date and pupils.pupilnumber, do so.

Comment: thank you but I don't at the moment and its something I cant change at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Worrying about query performance but not indexing your tables is, well, looking for a kind word here... ummm... daft.  That's the whole point of indexes.  **Any** variation on the query is going to be much slower than it needs to be.

I'd guess that using analytic functions would be the most efficient approach since it avoids the need to hit the table twice.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM( SELECT pupilnumber, 
               startDate,
               reg,
               rank() over (partition by pupilnumber order by startDate desc) rnk
          FROM registered )
 WHERE rnk = 1
   AND reg = 'Y'
```

Comment: Daft is  much kinder word than I would choose.

Answer (score 0):

You can look execution plan for this query. It will show you high cost operations. If you see table scan in execution plan you should index them. Also you can try "exists" instead of "in".

Answer (score 0):

This query MIGHT be more efficient for you and hope at a minimum you have indexes per "pupilnumber" in the respective tables.

To clarify what I am doing, the first inner query is a join between the registered table and the pupil which pre-qualifies that they DO Exist in the pupil table... You can always re-add the "partition" reference if that helps.  From that, it is grabbing both the pupil AND their max date so it is not doing a correlated subquery for every student... get all students and their max date first...

THEN, join that result to the registration table... again by the pupil AND the max date being the same and qualify the final registration status as YES.  This should give you the count you need.

```
select
      count(*) as RegisteredPupils
   from
      ( select 
              t2.pupilnumber,
              max( t2.Start_Date ) as MostRecentReg
           from
              registered t2
                 join Pupils p
                    on t2.pupilnumber = p.pupilnumber
           group by
              t2.pupilnumber ) as MaxPerPupil
         JOIN registered t1
            on MaxPerPupil.pupilNumber = t1.pupilNumber
           AND MaxPerPupil.MostRecentRec = t1.Start_Date
           AND t1.Reg = 'Y'
```

Note:  If you have multiple records in the registration table, such as a person taking multiple classes registered on the same date, then you COULD get a false count.  If that might be the case, you could change from

```
COUNT(*)
```

to

```
COUNT( DISTINCT T1.PupilNumber )
```